# Converting dataURI to file for upload via REST does not work but normal filefield upload works fine

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, rest, data-uri

I have implemented a solution that accepts a single file upload (image for profile) in a Django Rest Framework backend. This route api/people/id/upload_image. Only accepts a parameter with an image. and can be used via HTTP POST.
When uploading via a fileinput field in eg. Postman, the default Django API or via browser fetch() in my Vue.js application is no problem. So it seems as long as it is a default form-upload field it is doing its job.

But in my frond-end (vuejs 3) I am using an image-cropper. Users can upload an image and via the javascript cropper the image can be cropped. This is important for the UI because I need a square image. The cropper uses HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() as export format.

And what seemed to be not that difficult gets me stuck for days now. I just can't find a way to convert and POST the cropped image in such a way that is accepted by the upload_image API backend. I am using Fetch() for sending this POST call.

I am not a javascript expert so I get my knowledge via internet and I tried it in several ways; with first creating a BLOB from the dataURI, and by creating a File before feeding it to dataForm and send it as :body in Fetch()

The dataURI seems OK because I am also replacing the cropped image directly in the HTML. And that looks totally fine. The API is responding with an 'HTTP 200 OK'. But the old image is not being replaced.

So my assumption is that there is something wrong with the image send to the API, because via normal fileupload everything works fine. How should I convert this dataURI in a proper way so it can be send and accepted by the API endpoint. And how should the API call look like: headers, body..

this is my last attempt in converting and sending the cropped image: (dataURIimage is OK)

```
uploadPhoto(context, dataURIimage) {
        const blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURIimage);
        const resultFile = new File([blob], "picture", {
          type: "image/png"
        });
  
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("image", resultFile); 
  
        const headerToken = "Token" + " " + this.getters.getToken;
        const url =
          "https://workserver-7e6s4.ondigitalocean.app/api/people/" +
          this.getters.getProfiel.id +
          "/upload_image/";
        fetch(url, {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': headerToken,
          },
          body: formData,
        })
          .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.status)
            if (response.ok) {
              return response.json();
            }
          })
          .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data.image);
          })
          .catch(function(error) {
            alert(error + " " + ":ERROR");
          });
      },



function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string
    // doesn't handle URLEncoded DataURIs - see SO answer #6850276 for code that does this
    var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];

    // write the bytes of the string to an ArrayBuffer
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
    var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
      ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
  }
```

Martijn dekker

Comment: Just a thought, but, if you're struggling with converting this on the client side, why not just post the dataUri string to django and perform the conversion there?

Comment: Well, I thought about that. And that is my last resort. Hope to fix this front-end so I don't have to change the backend functionality

Comment: @MDekker Have you tried not wrapping the `Blob` in `File`, and just sending the blob directly?